# Resize Image in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, image-resizing

I used this code to resize the image

```
foreach (var file in imgworksample)
{               
        var filesize = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream());                     
        var scaleImage = ImageResize.Scale(filesize, 400, 700);
        scaleImage.SaveAs(imagePath + file.FileName);
        size += file.Length;
}
```

But it did not work.

What method should I use to resize the image?

Comment: Are you using any custom nuget? [this one](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v4.0/index.md) could help.

Comment: yes, it is but its not work

Comment: What is the nuget you are using?

Comment: version 3.0.2 I using

Comment: https://tutexchange.com/how-to-crop-and-resize-image-in-asp-net-core/
please check above solution

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Just in case, that code is for an older version [relevant code is here](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v3.0/index.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I think it should work.

```
foreach (var file in imgworksample)
{               
       
        var img = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream());
        img.Mutate(x => x.Resize(400, 700));
        img.Save(imagePath + file.FileName);
        size += file.Length;
}
```

Update

```
Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -IncludePrerelease
```

Comment: "Load" dosn't definition at Image

Comment: @AliKhansari have you made your parameter image IFormFile type?

Comment: yes I using IFormFile,Image upload works well ,But resizing does not work well

Comment: ```Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -IncludePrerelease```then it will work fine.

Comment: @AliKhansari I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: thanks it's worked, I Updated Your answer

Comment: @AliKhansari Glad to know :)